# How do I handle this Java/netty exception?

Tags: java, exception, netty

I'm running a netty server on linux, and see a lot of exceptions associated with clients' disconnections.

I'd prefer to minimize these exceptions' messages to a couple of words or totally hide them. How do I do that?

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:447)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:110)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Catch it and log whatever you want to log?

Comment: IOException is a checked exception and should be handled, not thrown or just ignored. How to handle the exception depends on your application. In most cases, it's necessary to close the connection or do cleanup tasks after. There are various tutorials on Java exception handling.

Comment: I can't find where in the code I should catch it.

Answer (score 3):

In netty inbound handlers implement

```
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Exception cause)
```

in that function you can just say

```
if (cause instance of IOException) ...
```